# How to print an array in php one click at a time

Tags: php, arrays, primes

I need to print an array (more specifically prime numbers) one 'click' at a time. I have created the prime array but I am not sure how to it run like user is clicking a button "next" and the next prime number shows up and then he clicks next and another one shows up. Or maybe there is a better way doing this?

Here is the prime array:

```
$primes = array();
for ($x = 2; $x <= 1000; $x++) {
    $xIsPrime = TRUE;
    $sqrtX = sqrt($x);
    foreach ($primes as $prime) if ($prime > $sqrtX || ((!($x % $prime)) && (!$xIsPrime = FALSE))) break;
    if ($xIsPrime) echo ($primes[] = $x)  . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: You need to use `AJAX` for it.

Comment: If you want unique prime number, then keep array in session / cookie and then mark them as used once used.

Comment: just a side note. Use `Sieve of Eratosthenes` algorithm for generating prime numbers. link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: This will be done in the browser, yes? Is there anything preventing you from generating the prime numbers in Javascript?

Comment: I only know php, I am trying to learn by limiting things within php. I am hoping to start learning JS in a couple of months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These things are best done with Javascript but, since your question is tagged PHP, I’ve written the following code:

```
<?php
$primes = array(2,   3,   5,   7,  11,  13,  17,  19,  23,  29, 
               31,  37,  41,  43,  47,  53,  59,  61,  67,  71, 
               73,  79,  83,  89,  97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 
              127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173);
// Add as many primes as you wish to the array
$num = array_key_exists("hid", $_POST) ? $_POST["hid"]+1 : 0;
?>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Put your meta tags, title, Javascript and CSS here -->
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
<h2><?php print($primes[$num]); ?></h2>
<?php
if(sizeof($primes)-$num > 1){
?>
<input type="hidden" name="hid" value="<?php print($num); ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Next Prime"/>
<?php
}
else{
?>
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Next Prime" disabled/>
<?php
}
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped. I don't know JS yet, I am learning php so I am trying to limit doing to code and learn in the process. Everyone else thanks for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: See my updated answer. The submit button will be disabled as soon as the user will reach the greatest prime number in this code. Though you didn’t ask for it, I added this facility because it’ll make things easier (hopefully).

Comment: Thanks, thats a user friedly way to do it. On an unrelated note, How long have you been programming in PHP and how long did it take you to be "good" at it? Any tips is highly appreciated.

Comment: You’re welcome. I’ve been PHP-ing since 2009 but I don’t think I’ve achieved knowledge/skill enough to give you any advice. It took me two days to learn the basics of PHP. I’ve been making a very slow progress since then. In fact, I’m a student of English literature and programming is simply one of my hobbies. Wish you all the best for your learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use querystring to determine up to what number have the prime shown and find the next prime number based on that.

```
$begin = isset($_GET['num']) ? $_GET['num'] : 2;
for ($x = $begin; $x <= 1000; $x++) {
    ...
    if ($xIsPrime) {
        echo $x  . "<br>";
        echo "<a href='...?num=$x'>next</a>";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ajax or you can do a CRUD system using PHP (which would require a page refresh each time)

Psuedo code:

Say your script is at /primes.php (and this is the page you are on)

First - because your list is static - run you script and output all the prime numbers to an array - there is no point generating them each time.

On you page the user sees you would have a form with a hidden field containing the last shown prime number (lets say 3 for ease).

You would then post this to your script using the action='primes.php'

Get the posted data - then simply find the position in the array of the last known prime number (3 in this case - which will return position 1 (remember arrays are 0 indexed!)

Then just query the array for the next prime number (so with you returned 1 (lets say held in `$lastPrime` and with an array called `$primes` just ask for `$primes($lastPrime +1) - this will give you the next prime which you can add into the hidden field again.)

hopefully that will help you work it out.

If you were using Ajax - do exactly the same but just update the hidden field OR you can use a local javascript variable to store the current / last value.